# Can I insert into a map by key in F#?

Tags: dictionary, f#

I'm messing around a bit with F# and I'm not quite sure if I'm doing this correctly. In C# this could be done with an IDictionary or something similar.

```
type School() =
   member val Roster = Map.empty with get, set

   member this.add(grade: int, studentName: string) =
      match this.Roster.ContainsKey(grade) with
        | true -> // Can I do something like this.Roster.[grade].Insert([studentName])?
        | false -> this.Roster <- this.Roster.Add(grade, [studentName])
```

Is there a way to insert into the map if it contains a specified key or am I just using the wrong collection in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The F# `Map` type is a mapping from keys to values just like ordinary .NET `Dictionary`, except that it is immutable.

If I understand your aim correctly, you're trying to keep a list of students for each grade. The type in that case is a map from integers to lists of names, i.e. `Map<int, string list>`.

The `Add` operation on the map actually either *adds* or *replaces* an element, so I think that's the operation you want in the `false` case. In the `true` case, you need to get the current list, append the new student and then replace the existing record. One way to do this is to write something  like:

```
type School() =
   member val Roster = Map.empty with get, set

   member this.Add(grade: int, studentName: string) =
     // Try to get the current list of students for a given 'grade'
     let studentsOpt = this.Roster.TryFind(grade) 
     // If the result was 'None', then use empty list as the default 
     let students = defaultArg studentsOpt []
     // Create a new list with the new student at the front
     let newStudents = studentName::students
     // Create & save map with new/replaced mapping for 'grade'
     this.Roster <- this.Roster.Add(grade, newStudents)
```

This is not thread-safe (because calling `Add` concurrently might not update the map properly). However, you can access `school.Roster` at any time, iterate over it (or share references to it) safely,  because it is an immutable structure. However, if you do not care about that, then using standard `Dictionary` would be perfectly fine too - depends on your actual use case.

Comment: Or `ConcurrentDictionary` ... ?

Comment: Thanks, Tomas! I'm thinking it may be best to use the Dictionary, as you mentioned. Your answer does help a lot in my general F# learning, however. The values in the dictionary can be sorted, as well, correct?

Comment: @Jon The framework's `Dictionary` doesn't store the data in any particular order (unlike the `SortedDictionary` and `SortedList`).  You can of course copy the data to a sorted collection, however.  The F# map is a binary tree, so, like SortedDictionary, it keeps the data in key order.  Unlike SortedDictionary, you can't specify a custom comparer.

Comment: @Jon also, you might want to consider designing this as an immutable data structure, since that is the F# idiom, after all.  In that case, the `add` method would return a new School instance with the added data.  Then you don't have to worry as much about thread safety.

Comment: @phoog I completely agree! Returning a new instance of school (wrapping a new instance of `Map` that you get) would be a nice immutable solution!

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the tips! I think I will try to use an immutable collection instead.

Comment: @Jon But there's no "instead" -- you can have an immutable School type that contains an immutable map.  The add method returns a new School instance whose map is the result of calling add on the first map.  that is, `type School(roster : Map<int, string list>) = member this.add(grade: int, studentName: string) = School(roster.Add(grade, studentName :: (match Map.tryFind grade roster with None -> [] | Some names -> names)))`.